# concatenate div into scraped content

Tags: php, domparser, simpledom

I'm using PHP simple dom parser, how should I insert extra entities within them? like $html contain

```
<table class="tb">..</table>
<table>..</table>
<table>..</table>
```

I know how to select the dom, like `$html->find('div[class="tb"][1]');`
but how to concatenate new div after it? like I want to put ads btw table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you still want simpledom example:

```
$banner = '<div class="ads">blablabla</div>';
$tables = $html->find('table');
foreach($tables as $table){
    $table->outertext .= $banner;
}
```

OR:

```
$html->find('div[class="tb"][1]').outertext .= '<div class="ads">blablabla</div>';
```

made after reading docs from [here](http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/manual.htm)  (: